# filling selectonemenu with mangaged property

Tags: jsp, jsf, java-ee-6, managed-bean

for a project i need to fill a selectonemenu with the values of a list initialized in the faces-config file. i just can't seem to find the right answer  hopefully someone can answer it for me.
why dont the values from faces-config  load into the selectonemenu?
im quite sure i have forgotten something but i have no idea, what i have forgotten. at the moment the selectonemenu is completly empty. below is a copy of my code.

faces-config:

```
<managed-bean-name>myBean</managed-bean-name>
<managed-bean-class>beans.MyBean</managed-bean-class>
<managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
<managed-property>
    <property-name>animals</property-name>
    <list-entries>
        <value>Cat</value>
        <value>Dog</value>
    </list-entries>
</managed-property>
```

MyBean

```
private String animal;
private List<SelectItem> animals;

public String getAnimal() {
    return animal;
}

public void setAnimal(String animal) {
    this.animal = animal;
}

public void setAnimals(List<String> items) {     
    animals = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    for (String item : items){
      animals.add(new SelectItem(item));
    }
}

public List<SelectItem> getAnimals() {        
    return animals;
}
```

index.xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.name}"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.age}"/>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="animal" value="#{myBean.animal}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.animals}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:commandButton value="press" action="page2"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: What is your problem? What doesn't work?

Comment: the values from faces-config don't load into the selectonemenu.